# How do I uninstall Fedora 23 (dual boot with Windows 10)?

Tags: fedora, windows, multi-boot, uninstall

[image: Disk Management on Windows 10]

This is the Disk Management on Windows 10. I have no idea what to remove. I don't have the installation disk as Windows 8 came pre-installed with my laptop. Please help me with this.

Comment: First I would ask why do you want to uninstall? To install something else, or to recover the disk space.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Windows will resize the partitions for you.  So there's no point deleting partitions in Windows, because you won't reclaim any space.

I think a better bet would be to use a Linux Live image.  Technically you could use the Fedora install media and install GParted on the live system.  However I think it makes more sense to use the [GParted live image](http://gparted.org/livecd.php).

GParted will show you the filesystem type of each partition.  Remove the filesystems with Linux types only.  If you're not sure, then the filesystem type should be `ext4`.  The main Windows filesystems should show up as `NTFS`, but there'll be at least one weird small one that shows up as neither that you don't want to delete either.

Before doing so, you need to **make sure you're not relying on the Linux bootloader GRUB** (GRUB probably uses a /boot partition you want to remove!).  I.e. you need to be able to get windows to reinstall its boot loader as the default.

You *should* be obtain Windows recovery media from a Windows 10 system.  **Make sure you do this before anything else (and seriously back up all your data**, because you might have to use the recovery media to reinstall in case something goes wrong - and hey, I'm a random internet person, I could easily be telling you wrong information.  I don't have enough experience with repairing Windows systems unfortunately).  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-10/create-a-recovery-drive